# ADSI Searcher - PowerShell get IP address after FindAll()

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am using

```
([adsisearcher]“objectcategory=computer”).FindAll()
```

and I am able to obtain a list of all connected devices to the AD. However, if I want to obtain the IP address of each device in a list fashion, how can I do that?

Please note that I do not have AD modules installed and am looking for a way to do it from the Command Prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is no attribute of Active Directory computer objects for IP addresses, either IPv4 or IPv6, you need to first get the list of computers and loop through that list to find the IP addresses.
Something like this (untested):

```
# you can add more properties if you need to
$properties = 'Name','OperatingSystem'
$searcher   = [adsisearcher]'(objectCategory=computer)'
$searcher.PropertiesToLoad.AddRange($properties)
$computers = $searcher.FindAll() 
$output = @()
foreach ($pc in $computers) {
    # get a list of IP addresses for each computer, filter on IPV4
    try {
        $name = $pc.Properties["name"]
        $ip = $null
        $ip = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry($name).AddressList | 
              Where-Object { $_.AddressFamily -eq 'InterNetwork' } | 
              Select-Object -ExpandProperty IPAddressToString
    }
    catch { 
        Write-Warning "Host '$name' could not be reached."
    }

    # create a PSObject with selected properties for each machine found
    $result = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
    foreach ($key in $properties) {
        # apparently, all property names must be lower case
        $name  = $key.ToLower()
        $value = $pc.Properties[$name]
        $result | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $key -Value $value
    }
    # add the 'IpV4Addresses' property
    $result | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'IpV4Addresses' -Value ($ip -join ', ')

    # output the resulting object
    $output += $result
}

# display the output on screen as table
$output | Format-Table -AutoSize  
# or $output | Format-List

# or save the output to a CSV file
# $output | Export-Csv -Path 'PATH AND FILENAME FOR THE EXPORT CSV' -NoTypeInformation
```

If you save this to a .ps1 file, you can run it from the Command prompt like this:

```
powershell.exe -noexit "& 'X:\Folder\GetComputers.ps1"
```

Hope that helps

P.S. In your code, you have curly 'smart-quotes'. It is always a good idea to replace them with regular, straight quotes.

Comment: Hello Theo, 
I tried running your script i ended up with the below, 
Exception calling "GetHostEntry" with "1" argument(s): "Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: address"
At line:3 char:5
+     $ip = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry($pc.Name).AddressList |
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentNullException

i was able to extract a list of hostnames but i got an exception on the IP selection .. any idea ?

Comment: i would very much appreciate your help :)

Comment: @TheBee sorry.. I forgot that using adsisearcher, the properties are returned inside the `Properties` property of the object. So, to get the pc name you have to do `$pc.Properties["Name"]`, not just `$pc.Name`. I have edited my answer. Could you try please?

Comment: Thank you very much mate, that worked perfectly .. however i still have a problem with the way they are displayed,

Comment: @TheBee By default PowerShell would display the result as a table. If you would rather have a list format you can do `$result | format-list`

Comment: Well i am getting a blank on the name on the OS only the IP address is being displayed

Comment: ROS...  Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard   172.12.1.1... 
i am getting the results with dots on the ends ... how can i fix this ? and i think after this is solved it would be completely solved

Comment: @TheBee When results are shown in table format (the default in PowerShell), they may be truncated to fit on screen. That does not mean the results themselves are truncated, it is just how PowerShell displays it. You can also do `$result | Format-List` so it will be displayed every property on a separate line.

Comment: @TheBee I put in some small change to capture the output in a `$output` variable. Like this, you will also be able to save the results to a CSV file if that is mote convenient for you.

Comment: thanks mate, however i do not have any admin rights on my powershell that is why am going with such an approach

Comment: @TheBee Ok, so writing a file is out of the question then? In that case, just remove or comment out the last line.

Comment: i did nothing is showing mate, the first code before the output was great ... yet the only issue i was facing was with the ellipses

Comment: @TheBee Oops.. minor mistake. Went too fast. Should be fixed now. If you still have ellipses, try the `$output | Format-List`

Comment: Its not outputting anything except the server names now .. 
the first modification was great i wanted them all in the same list .. i tried different variations they are going on seperate items.. and now nothing is being displayed

Comment: SNIPER  Windows Server 2008
LOTA  Windows Server 2008
CON... Windows Server 2008
its not changing

Comment: @TheBee As I have commented before, it is just the way PowerShell formats the data on screen. The data itself is NOT truncated. Use `$output | Format-List` for a different view or save the output as CSV file.